# Agregar múltiples valores al RequestMapping que contengan la cadena

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring

Tengo un RequestMapping que tiene una URL /algo, pero deseo aplicar el mismo a las URL que contengan /algo-otracosa, ¿Cómo podría cambiar el valor para que acepte estos resultados?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/algo")
public class MyController extends AbstractPageController {
   /*Resto del código*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución es simple, ya que la propiedad [`value`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#value--) del [RequestMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) es un arreglo de `String`s:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/algo", "/otra-cosa", "/otro-algo"})
public class MyController extends AbstractPageController {
   /*Resto del código*/
}
```

Incluso puedes omitir el nombre de la propiedad:

```
@RequestMapping({"/algo", "/otra-cosa", "/otro-algo"})
public class MyController extends AbstractPageController {
   /*Resto del código*/
}
```